# How can I specify a maximum service duration in systemd service?

Tags: systemd, timeout, systemd-timer

I have a problem where on rare occasions my `Type=simple` systemd service hangs or gets caught in a loop.  This causes its timer to stop scheduling the service because, as confirmed with `sudo systemctl status myservice`, the service is still running when it should have long exited.  I haven't yet figured out the bug but it isn't critical.  But in the mean time I don't want it to stop scheduling future runs.

Is there a way to specify in the systemd service file a maximum run time, after which it will force stop?

```
[Unit]
Description=scripts should run and exit but occasionally hangs or infinite loop      

[Service]
SyslogIdentifier=myservice
Environment='MYVAR=myvar'
User=deanresin
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/deanresin/myscript
```

Comment: A service that runs and exits should be of type `oneshot`, not `simple`

Comment: Thanks! I was always confused between `Type` `simple` and `oneshot` even after reading the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TimeoutStartSec` should be used. As @muru mentioned in the comment, the correct way to run a script that should exit is to use `Type=oneshot` instead of `Type=simple`.

For example, if your script is normally executed in under 10 seconds, your config would be:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
TimeoutStartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=myservice
Environment='MYVAR=myvar'
User=deanresin
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/deanresin/myscript
```

If the script takes more than 10 seconds to execute, it will be killed, and the service would show as failed.

Comment: I think you need to remove the "s" from `TimeoutStartSec=10s`.

Comment: According to the documentation, either `10` or `10s` would work equally well, but I removed the trailing `s` from the command as it's not needed.

Comment: I think it was a little ambiguous.  It said for long time `5m12s` it takes units but for only seconds it is unit-less.  But that isn't really clear that it won't work with a unit and it wouldn't make sense for it to not work.  Such a strange design decision and poor documentation.